# Kniting R markdown document to PDF

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex

I know that similar questions exist, but i recently updated R studio, and I now cannot knit to pdf

```
output file: assigment-1-v2.knit.md


tlmgr.pl: Remote database (revision 70146 of the texlive-scripts package)
seems to be older than the local installation (rev 70172 of
texlive-scripts); please use a different mirror and/or wait a day or two.

tlmgr update --self

tlmgr.pl: Remote database (revision 70146 of the texlive-scripts package)
seems to be older than the local installation (rev 70172 of
texlive-scripts); please use a different mirror and/or wait a day or two.

! LaTeX Error: File `pdflscape.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile assigment-1-v2.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See assigment-1-v2.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I have tried updating tidytex but it did not work!

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I do not understand what the error means!

Comment: Have you included the CTAN package `pdflscape` in the yaml header?

Comment: The important message is the first one.  Somehow you have a newer local database of LaTeX packages than the mirror you are using to update it.  Maybe RStudio distributes a particular version, or sets a bad mirror?  What you could try is this: start a Terminal in RStudio, and run `tlmgr option repository ctan`, then `tlmgr update --self`.  You may need to use "sudo" or "Run as admin" to get those to work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the responses! I have just tried running this `tlmgr option repository ctan` in the R terminal, and I get a response that says ` 'tlmgr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. Do I need to install tlmgr, and if so, how would I go about doing that?